# on click for jquery not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done on hover and on click with jQuery plenty of times, but this is baffling me. I have the jQuery library imported, and I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content_main_left_bottom').bind("click", function(e) {
        alert('hi');

    });
});
```

For some reason, it's NEVER reaching the alert!! I even put the alert right above document and it's showing there. I have the div tag with `content_main_left_bottom` within my code somewhere, is there something else I should do with that class?

Comment: What version of jquery ar eyou using? Depending on the version you may want to use .on which is most current. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: did you check your firebug console for errors? ... if it sais $ is not defined you need to change your first line of code to **jQuery(document).ready(function($) {**

Comment: Is the `$(document).ready(...)` handler definitely firing?

Comment: Consider creating a testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Maybe you don't have a `...main_left_bottom`. Eeeek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.content_main_left_bottom').bind("click", function(e) {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

first i would try this if the element with CLASS name (not ID) content_main_left_bottom exists it should work fine ...except you have any other javascript error in the code which you can find out by pushing f12 in your browser and go to the console section